# Sense HAT set_pixels TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been writing a competition entry, trying to make an mp3 player with the Raspberry Pi Sense HAT. I have added a play function with `pygame.mixer.music` and I want to have patterns to display on the screen (randomly generated from a selection), but when I run my program, I only get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Astro Pi/MP3 Player/player.py", line 90, in <module>
    display()
  File "/home/pi/Astro Pi/MP3 Player/player.py", line 65, in display
    sense.set_pixels(pattern_one)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sense_hat/sense_hat.py", line 268, in set_pixels
    if len(pix) != 3:
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Can you help? Here is my full code...

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# Import the SenseHAT libraries and set them up for easy access
from sense_hat import SenseHat
sense = SenseHat()
# Import the other libraries I need for the MP3 player
import time, os, pygame.mixer, random, glob
# Make sure that the music will play out of the Audio Jack socket
def display():
    colors = [[178,31,53],[216,39,53],[255,116,53],[255,161,53],[255,203,53],[255,249,53],[0,117,58],[0,158,71],[22,221,52],[0,82,165],[0,121,231],[0,169,252],[104,30,126],[125,60,181],[189,122,246]] 
    a = random.choice(colors)
    b = random.choice(colors)
    c = random.choice(colors)
    choice = random.randint(1,5)
    pattern_one = [
        a,0,0,b,b,0,0,a,
        0,a,0,b,b,0,a,0,
        0,0,a,b,b,a,0,0,
        b,b,b,a,a,b,b,b,
        b,b,b,a,a,b,b,b,
        0,0,a,b,b,a,0,0,
        0,a,0,b,b,0,a,0,
        a,0,0,b,b,0,0,a
        ]
    pattern_two = [
        a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,
        b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,
        a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,
        b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,
        a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,
        b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,
        a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,
        b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a
        ]
    pattern_three = [
        a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,
        a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,
        a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,
        a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,
        a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,
        a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,
        a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,
        a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b
        ]
    pattern_four = [
        a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,
        b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,
        a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,
        b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,
        a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,
        b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,
        a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,
        b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,
        ]
    pattern_five = [
        a,a,b,b,b,b,a,a,
        a,a,b,b,b,b,a,a,
        a,a,c,c,c,c,a,a,
        a,a,c,c,c,c,a,a,
        a,a,b,b,b,b,a,a,
        a,a,b,b,b,b,a,a,
        a,a,c,c,c,c,a,a,
        a,a,c,c,c,c,a,a
        ]
    if choice == 1:
        sense.set_pixels(pattern_one)
    elif choice == 2:
        sense.set_pixels(pattern_two)
    elif choice == 3:
        sense.set_pixels(pattern_three)
    elif choice == 4:
        sense.set_pixels(pattern_four)
    elif choice == 5:
        sense.set_pixels(pattern_five)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    sense.clear()
os.system("sudo amixer cset numid=3 1")
# Make sure that the volume is turned up so that pygame can control it
os.system("sudo amixer cset numid=1 100%")
# Initialise pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
# Look for all the .mp3 files in the 'songs' folder and put their file names in a list
songs = glob.glob('songs/' + '*.mp3')
# Choose a random file from the list and load it up to start with
pygame.mixer.music.load(random.choice(songs))
# Make sure the volume is up to 100%
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(1.0)
# Play the song
pygame.mixer.music.play()
while True:
    display()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's because you are using zeroes in your pattern matrices, RGB lists are needed instead. Try to set those zeros to some color (i guess black) like in this reference:
https://pythonhosted.org/sense-hat/api/#set_pixels

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat

sense = SenseHat()

X = [255, 0, 0]  # Red
O = [255, 255, 255]  # White

question_mark = [
O, O, O, X, X, O, O, O,
O, O, X, O, O, X, O, O,
O, O, O, O, O, X, O, O,
O, O, O, O, X, O, O, O,
O, O, O, X, O, O, O, O,
O, O, O, X, O, O, O, O,
O, O, O, O, O, O, O, O,
O, O, O, X, O, O, O, O
]

sense.set_pixels(question_mark)
```